# style every div after a certain div

Tags: css, html

I would like to change the style of all the entries following a certain div. See example. Is this possible with child selectors? Thanks!

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="entry">content</div>
    <div class="entry">content</div>
    <div class="CHANGE">content</div>
    <div class="entry">content</div>
    <div class="entry">content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This selector :

```
div.CHANGE ~ div {your rules;}
```

Comment: It's CSS3 and not as widely implemented as you would like, of course. You better use it through jQuery to ensure cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: Looks like [the general sibling combinator works in IE7 and up](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t30).

Comment: IE7+ is all I need. Thanks everybody

Answer (score 2):

For elements `directly` under `div.wrapper`.

```
div.wrapper > div {your rules;}
```